# How to add permissions in Spring Security ACL

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In the context of a Spring Boot project using Spring Security ACLs, I'm giving administation permission to the user who creates the object in the first place:

```java
ObjectIdentity objectIdentity = new ObjectIdentityImpl(MyClass.class, myObject.getId());
Sid sid = new PrincipalSid(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
MutableAcl acl = aclService.createAcl(objectIdentity);
acl.insertAce(0, BasePermission.ADMINISTRATION, sid, true);
aclService.updateAcl(acl);
```

How can I later give other selected users READ and WRITE permissions this object?

Comment: The SID you're adding in `acl.insertAce(0, BasePermission.ADMINISTRATION, sid, true);` is not limited to the owner-SID, here you'd use the SID of the user you want to add and define the permissions it has on the object. So something like `acl.insertAce(1, BasePermission.READ | BasePermission.WRITE, otherUserSID, true);` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks @RomanVottner. One thing I noticed is that I cannot bitwise OR permissions like you did in the example as the `|` operator is not defined for the `Permission` class. Does that mean I have to create a separate ACEs for `READ` and `WRITE` permissions?

Comment: I was refering to that on top of my head, [though this only works on bitmasks](https://github.com/RovoMe/spring-security-acl-mongodb/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/acls/mongodb/MongoDBMutableAclServiceTest.java#L160) and the respective `DomainObjectPermission` is a custom one. The closest thing is probably [Spring's CumulativePermission](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.20.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/acls/domain/CumulativePermission.html)

Comment: @RomanVottner yes CumulativePermission looks good! By the way do you know any good learning resources regarding Spring ACLs? I've not seen many good tutorials around.

Comment: A good point to start is always the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html). As for so many things [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-acl) has a hands-on tutorial. Spring also used to have a [Contacts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/sample-apps.html) sample application that is worth looking at, though it seems that after `3.0.7-RELEASE` it was removed somehow